# request.Headers["Authorization"] = "Bearer " + accessToken;

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, azure-mobile-services

Im using azure mobile service for xamarin forms. I was using non-secureed services it was opened to use. Now client changed the service end point and now end points are secured only authorized user can access the endpoints, so now im logged in with Google account. I have followed the steps:-

1. Logged in with google account and received the access token.
2. Pass access token in get request header.

> request.Headers["Authorization"] = "Bearer " + accessToken;

Response:-

> The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized.

If anybody have any idea please share with me.

Comment: I am using Google token to sent request to mobile service end point, Should i send google token to azure for authentication?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use a Google token to authenticate directly.  You swap the google token for a ZUMO token and then add the X-ZUMO-AUTH header with the value of the ZUMO token.

We generally assume you are using one of the client SDKs.  However, since you are doing this directly, you will need to construct the request yourself.  The endpoint is /login/google and the POST body should be an application/json with the contents `{"access_token","your-google-token"}`.

Two recommendations: 1) Use the Client SDK (you can over-ride the HttpClient using a delegating handler and a lot of this stuff is taken care of for you).  2) Upgrade to Azure Mobile Apps (Azure Mobile Services is being shut down this year, and all customers are being transitioned to Azure Mobile Apps).

Comment: You are right, request will work with x-zumo-auth header, because last night i have tried the same thing. like :-  request.Headers["x-zumo-auth"] = accessToken;

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this solves your problem, but in my case following code works (with the bearer token, `HttpClient` and Xamarin.Forms)

```
// Set the authorization Header in httpclient
DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", "your-access-token");
```

side-note: I have an own implementation for the API-communication (which just inherits from `HttpClient`)